# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, nosql, mongo

Я только начинаю изучать `spring-data-mongodb`

**Мой проект Non-Boot (я не наследуюсь от spring-boot-starter-parent, все по-старинке)**

Эта ошибка выскакивает, когда я пытаюсь сохранить документ:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.insertOne(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult;
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.lambda$insertDocument$16(MongoTemplate.java:1464)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:553)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insertDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1458)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:1257)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:1172)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:91)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:599)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.save(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.nastyabakhshieva.controllers.MainController.createNewUser(MainController.java:34)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

**Сервер MongoDB запущен**

Возможно, я не добавила что-то важное в конфиг:

```
package com.example.nastyabakhshieva.config;

import com.example.nastyabakhshieva.repositories.RepositoryPackageMarker;
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = RepositoryPackageMarker.class)
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${mongodb.address}")
    private String mongoAddress;

    @Value("${mongodb.database.name}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return databaseName;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(mongoAddress);
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();

        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), databaseName);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
        return Collections.singleton("com.example");
    }
}
```

```
//application.poperties
mongodb.address=mongodb://localhost:27017
mongodb.database.name=spring-project
```

Это класс и репозиторий:

```
package com.example.nastyabakhshieva.repositories;

import com.example.nastyabakhshieva.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
}
```

```
package com.example.nastyabakhshieva.model;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}
```

Мои зависимоси:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.springframework.version>5.3.6</org.springframework.version>
        <java.servlets.api.version>4.0.1</java.servlets.api.version>
        <jackson.version>2.12.3</jackson.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.20</lombok.version>
        <spring.data.mongodb.version>3.2.0</spring.data.mongodb.version>
        <mongo.java.driver>3.12.8</mongo.java.driver>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${java.servlets.api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.mongodb.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongo.java.driver}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Если я что-то забыла, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Аналогичная проблема [тут](https://question-it.com/questions/503667/spring-boot-nosuchmethoderror). Похоже на проблему с версиями.

Comment: Я уже успела погуглить) Спринг бут сам управляет версиями, у меня же все мануально (тоесть у меня нет spring-boot-starter-parent)

Comment: Найдешь решение, положи сюда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наилучший вариант:

```
<!--<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${mongo.java.driver}</version>
</dependency>-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Небезопасный вариант (тоже может приводить к ошибкам):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.data.mongodb.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${mongo.java.driver}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

проблема в том что Вы используете --спринг--, пардон, несовместимые версии библиотек.
как уже подсказывали в каментах, если выскакивает NoSuсhMethodError, то наиболее вероятная причина лежит в том, что код компилировался с одной версией библиотеки, а запускается с другой, причем бинарно несовместимой.

судя по стэктрейсу очевидно, что класс org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate получил несовместимую версию класса com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection отностиельно той с которой он компилировался.

попробуйте версию монго драйвера, которую предложил Александр в соседнем ответе.

если же это не поможет то в общем случае рекомендую начать с дерева зависимостей

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

и смотреть какую версию транзитивно ожидают непосредственные зависимости.

иногда помогает удаление прямой зависимости и работа только с транзитивной, например, если не принципиально использовать конкретную версию драйвера, я бы удалил прямую зависимость на mongodb-driver-sync т.к. [spring-data-mongodb](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/3.2.0) и так привносит эту зависимость.